# React-Native Warning: Overwriting font Family style attribute preprocessor

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm getting the following warning:

"***Overwriting font Family style attribute preprocessor***" coming out from `StyleSheet.js` when running the app on iOS simulator. I haven't tested on Android yet though.

App.tsx

```html
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~43.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.13.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.10.5",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.66.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.32",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.66.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

[image]

Is it a package problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is coming straight from expo if you have `expo-font` installed.

This is the line of code in `node_modules/expo/build/Expo.fx.js` that leads to that warning:

```
// If expo-font is installed and the style preprocessor is available, use it to parse fonts.
if (StyleSheet.setStyleAttributePreprocessor) {
  StyleSheet.setStyleAttributePreprocessor('fontFamily', Font.processFontFamily);
```

The line from `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js` that raises the warning:

```
if (__DEV__ && typeof value.process === 'function') {
  console.warn(`Overwriting ${property} style attribute preprocessor`);
}
```

It seems like the best thing to do would be to hide the warning for now by adding the following lines to the top of your `App.js` or `index.js`:

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  "Overwriting fontFamily style attribute preprocessor"
]);
```

Comment: In general, a more general solution is preferred.

Comment: @jb1 I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: this is a perfectly fine answer. The idea of hardcoding entire messages like this just doesn't thrill me  :)

Comment: This makes me squirm, too. There just doesn't seem to be any other way around it right now :/

Comment: plz more elaborate your answer with file names & file path i am unable to fine these thing.

Comment: @AdeelAhmedBaloch I updated the answer to include the exact paths of the files referenced, as well as the files where you can make the changes to hide that warning.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue buy upgrading "react-native" to version "0.70.5".

This can be done by running:

```
npx expo install react-native@0.70.5
```

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same issue as I tried to upgrade my react native dependency , change "react-native": "0.66.1" to "react-native": "0.64.2", and then run

```
yarn install
or
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks @abdemirze downgrading react-native is what I always want to avoid. so I may just stick with `LogBox.ignoreLogs([".."])` for now.

Comment: Downgrading two React Native versions may have other unwanted implications. For example, some other dependencies might also have to be downgraded and you don't want to miss out on all the new React Native improvements just because of this warning.